# Google Maps InfoWindow - InfoBox Code

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I am trying to implement the 'InfoBox' code from the Google site into my existing Javascript code but I keep getting the following error 'InfoBox is undefined'. I've checked my code against the original and I just can't find out what the problem is. Would it be at all possible please that someone could take a look at this and let me know where I'm going wrong.

In addition, I would also like, if at all possible please, for someone to show me how I would make the InfoBox appear on the marker click, panning the map so that the marker is centred on the map and as each marker is clicked the InfoBox moving and appearing next to the marker that has been clicked.

Many thanks and kind regards

Chris

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>All Locations</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/alllocationsstyle.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/infobox.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var customIcons = {
            0: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            },
            3: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            }
            };

            function load() { 
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), { 
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.312195845815246,-4.45948481875007), 
            zoom:6, 
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap' 
            }); 

            // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file 
            downloadUrl("phpfile.php", function(data) { 
            var xml = data.responseXML; 
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker"); 
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
            var locationname = markers[i].getAttribute("locationname"); 
            var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
            var finds = markers[i].getAttribute("finds");
            var totalfinds = markers[i].getAttribute("totalfinds");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng( 
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("osgb36lat")), 
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("osgb36lon")));
            var icon = customIcons[totalfinds] || {};
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({          
            map: map, 
            position: point,
            title: address,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
            }); 
            } 
            });
            var boxText = document.createElement("div");
            boxText.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 8px; background: yellow; padding: 5px;";
            var html = locationname + "<p>" + 'No. of finds: ' + "<b>" + totalfinds + "</b>" + "</p>";

            var myOptions = {
            content: boxText
            ,disableAutoPan: false
            ,maxWidth: 0
            ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0)
            ,zIndex: null
            ,boxStyle: { 
            background: "url('tipbox.gif') no-repeat"
            ,opacity: 0.75
            ,width: "280px"
            }
            ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
            ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
            ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
            ,isHidden: false
            ,pane: "floatPane"
            ,enableEventPropagation: false
            };

            var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
            ib.open(map, marker);

            } 

            function downloadUrl(url, callback) { 
            var request = window.ActiveXObject ? 
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : 
            new XMLHttpRequest; 

            request.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (request.readyState == 4) { 
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing; 
            callback(request, request.status); 
            } 
            }; 

            request.open('GET', url, true); 
            request.send(null); 
            } 

            function doNothing() {} 

            </script> 
            </head> 

            <body onLoad="load()">
                <div id="map"></div>
            </body> 
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be that your js/infobox.js file is not loaded correctly.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for replying to my post. I've been back to the code and resaved it, but unfortunately I'm still getting the same problem. Regards Chris.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your path to "js/infobox.js" is right. Also, beware that when you declare "var ib = new InfoBox", ib is local to your load() function, and will disappear when you exit the function. Might be better to make ib global. (Here's my own experience with infobox: [An Alternative to the InfoWindow](http://www.mvjantzen.com/blog/?p=2912))